# Google Spreadsheet Parsing Issue

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When trying to sum up a few items from an =importhtml function, I get results that sheets turns into text making it impossible to use for calculations. Is there a way to stop this from happening or converting the resulting output to a numeric value? It only is an issue for "positive" numbers like +2.

[image: example]

I have already tried to use the value function with no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to convert the imported range:

```
=LET(i,IMPORT....., ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(i,"^\+(\d+)")),i)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. While I don't fully understand what this does, it did accomplish what I was looking for. Thank you again. -Eliot

Comment: Basically, REGEXEXTRACT checks for digits after the +sign in each cell and VALUE converts it to number. If it's not a number (so, it gives an error), it returns the original text (i). I'm glad it was useful!